# Windows 8.1 WPF controls in a Universal Application

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, devexpress, win-universal-app

I was wondering if you can use Windows 8.1 controls in a Universal Application?  Our company has two different tools set purchased which contain a set of tools that I need to utilize in a Windows 10 Universal application that I am developing, mainly gauges and graphs and want to make sure I won't run into any problems.  Otherwise I will need to roll my own or find another means.

Comment: Do you mean the DevExpress Windows 8 XAML Controls package? Why have you tagged WPF? And why not ask DevExpress? They can give you a definitive answer very quickly.

Comment: If you mean the DevExpress WPF package then you are likely to run into a lot of problems as WPF and universal apps are quite different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the the [DevExpress WPF controls](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/) neither in WinRT(Win8 XAML) nor in UWP(Win10 Universal App) development because all of these platforms are powered by absolutely different technologies.

If you are talking about the WinRT-development under Windows 8.1 you should use the [Windows 8 XAML Controls](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinRT/) suite.

IF you are talking about the Universal App developement under brand new Windows 10 you should use the UWP controls suite. AFAIK the DevExpress UWP controls [ships in beta status right now](http://newsletters.devexpress.com/Newsletter/2015-08-UWP-Beta/online.html?utm_source=UWP_Beta&utm_medium=OnlineVersion&utm_campaign=Newsletter&utm_content=Newsletter_UWP_Beta_OnlineVersion).

Related links(tutorials):

- [Install DevExpress UWP Controls, Run Demos and Explore the Toolbox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HLa015zBFH0&utm_source=UWP_Beta&utm_medium=VideoIntro&utm_campaign=Newsletter&utm_content=Newsletter_UWP_Beta_VideoIntro)
- [Re-use Code from an Existing Windows 8.1 Application](https://www.devexpress.com/go/Newsletter_UWP_Beta_VideoReuse.aspx)
- [Create a Windows 10 Universal App from Scratch](https://www.devexpress.com/go/Newsletter_UWP_Beta_VideoCreate.aspx)

Comment: Thank you .. i appreciate the response